# Listview, onItemClickListener and EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView with EditText inside.
Actually, when i touch an element of the `Listview`, the `EditText` have the focus and the keyboard appeared. Good.
The problem is i wanna do something on this EditText throught the listView's onItemClickListener, but seems that my code never enter in this method.

I try some `setDescendantFocusability` to my Listview but don't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot.

```
public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> notes;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public NoteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> notes) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.notes = notes;
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return notes.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return notes.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id;
}


private class ViewHolder {
    EditText note;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listenote, null);
        holder.note = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.note);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.note.setText(notes.get(position));

    return convertView;


}


}
```

my main activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    notes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
        notes.add("note"+i);
    EditTextSelected = null;

    adapter = new NoteAdapter(this, notes);
    lv1 = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listeNote));
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv1.setClickable(true);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(FastItActivity.this, "hello", 200);
            t.show();

        }
    });
```

listenote.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/fond_note"
    />



 </TableLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/wooden_top"

>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listeNote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:divider="#00000000"

    >
</ListView>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Describe what behavior do you want to see, what are user doing? Maybe you don't need to wire `ListView`'s `onClickListener` and focus of `EditText`

Comment: I want that when the user click on item in the list, the keyboard appear and i can change for example the background color of the selected note, modify the height (wrap content), etc ... of course, actually, i just try to catch the event (with a toast).

Comment: Why do you need a keyboard for this? Show context menu when item is clicked for example, then choose editing option(change color, height), etc

Comment: sry for my english, what i wanted to mean is that the user click on an item (each line of my list view = edittext), then the system change the color, the height of the selected note. that's why i wanted to catch the event in my main activity with the setOnItemClickListener. Actually, when the user touch an item on the listview, the keyboard appear in order to edit the text in the edittext. is what i want that the system do, but i want also that the system modify some propriety of the selected edittext.

Comment: What don't you use `OnClickListener` handler of `EditText`? Implement your modifications inside `onClick` method of `EditText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your modifications from `ListView`'s `onItemClickListener` to your `EditText`'s `onClickListener`

In `NoteAdapter`'s `getView`:

```
holder.note = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.note);
holder.note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }

    });
```

or try this:

```
holder.note.setOnFocusListener(new View.OnFocusListener(){
@Override    
public void onFocus(){
   //do something
   }
}
```

`getView` method has *position* parameter so you'll be able to distinguish what `EditText` was clicked (if you need different actions with different `EditTexts`)

Comment: Thanks, i did that. The problem is now that the onClick event appear only if i double click on an item. Indeed, the first click open the keyboard but the setOnCLickListener is not "active". If i click again in the edittext, i have finally the onClickListener "active". 
How can my onClick can be active directly on the first click ? (So with one click, the keyboard appear and the event is handled)

Answer (score 0):

This article is pretty long but towards the middle/end he demonstrates an interactive listview which is exactly what you need. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

If you could post some code that would help.

Comment: The problem with that is that is the button which manage is event itself. I did that, but now when i click on time on the EditText, i have the keyboard and i need to click another time on the EditText in order to have the event. More over, i prefer to manage this event on the listview. but thanks anyway;

Comment: Sorry, it took time to format code for stackoverflow. About the setDescendat, i removed it on the code that i posted because it was not effective. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve a similar problem: which item in a list was selected when you embed several views in list item?!

I refuse to create a new listener for each item in the list.  I can't imagine that would scale well on such a resource constrained platform.  But, I found you can solve this problem by specializing `EditText` to set and retrieve the selected index in `onClick`.

Define your specialization:

```
package userInterface;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class IndexedEditText extends EditText {
    public int listIndex;

    public IndexedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public IndexedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public IndexedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Replace your EditText for your specialized class in the list **item** XML declaration.  Be sure to get the path to your new class right (in my case it's userInterface.IndexedEditText).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <userInterface.IndexedEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_first_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:hint="@string/select"
        android:inputType="none" />

    <!-- other views -->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Set `listIndex` in `getView`, and set your `OnClickListener` for each `IndexedEditText` instance:

```
public abstract class EditTextPairArrayAdapter <T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    static class ViewHolder {
        private WeakReference<IndexedEditText>  name;
        private WeakReference<EditText>  notes;

        public ViewHolder(IndexedEditText tv, EditText et) {
            name = new WeakReference<IndexedEditText>(tv);
            notes = new WeakReference<EditText>(et);
        }
    }


    int textViewId;
    int editTextId;
    int listItemId;
    List<T> list = null;
    WeakReference<Context> contextRef;


    //context is Activity that instantiates this array adapter
    //resourceId is the layout xml ID for your special row
    //textViewResourceId is any TextView ID in your special row xml def
    //editTextResourceId means nothing in this context
    //objects is the initial list of objects to present in UI
    public EditTextPairArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, int textViewResourceId, int editTextResourceId, List<T> objects)  {
        super(context, resourceId, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.listItemId = resourceId;
        this.textViewId = textViewResourceId;
        this.editTextId= editTextResourceId;
        this.list = objects;
        this.contextRef = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View       view       = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            if(inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(listItemId, null);

            IndexedEditText text = (IndexedEditText)view.findViewById(textViewId);
            EditText notes = (EditText) view.findViewById(editTextId);

            text.listIndex = position;
                    //Special sauce

            if(contextRef != null && contextRef.get() != null && (contextRef.get() instanceof View.OnClickListener)) {
                text.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) contextRef.get());
            }

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(text, notes);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Titem = this.getItem(position);
        if(item != null) {
            //special sauce
        }

        return view;
    }

    //add abstract methods for implementations to define special sauce
}
```

Finally, in your Activity that implements OnClickListener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v instanceof IndexedEditText) {
        Object obj = myList.get(((IndexedEditText)v).listIndex);
        //do stuff with obj         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to superimpose an EditText with a TextView and alternate gone/visible on both so that the EditText stops inducing bugs when hidden.